# Increase Windows taskbar thumbnail/preview size

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, thumbnails

Is there a way to increase the size of the mouse-over thumbnail size for Windows 7 task-bar items?

Ie, if I have multiple file explorers open and mouse-over them it would be nice to have larger, higher detailed thumbnails that were more indicative of the contents of each.

I do know that if you mouse-over them, the desktop shows you which one it is by fading the rest of the windows but I would still like to be able to increase the thumbnail size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Launch **Regedit.exe** and navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
   ```
2. Create a DWORD value named **MinThumbSizePx**.
3. Double-click **MinThumbSizePx** and set its value data accordingly. I set it to 350 (Decimal).
4. Kill the **Explorer** task in the task manager and restart Explorer.

Comment: Very clean and works great.

Comment: This works for Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 as well.

Comment: I used 600 for the value. Very nice manageable size.