# How to make Windows 10 taskbar thumbnail previews clearer and less blurred?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, taskbar, thumbnail-generator

Following yesterday's (12-Jul-2017) update of Windows 10, the taskbar thumbnail previews are significantly blurred and less useful in recognising open documents, and distinguishing one open document from another using the same application; for example, distinguishing between open Outlook emails or Adobe Acrobat PDF tabs.
This issue is close to, but not the same as, [How to make Windows 10 taskbar thumbnail previews bigger?](https://superuser.com/questions/958690/how-to-make-windows-10-taskbar-thumbnail-previews-bigger) where Super User explains how to increase the size on screen of the preview thumbnail.
Is there a parameter that sets the resolution, dpi perhaps, used by Explorer in its rendering of the thumbnail?

Screenshots:

Thumbnails for three PDF docs using Print-Screen pasted into Paint:
[image: thumbnails for three PDF docs using Print-Screen pasted into Paint]

Another thumbnail showing three Firefox windows:

[image: another thumbnail showing three Firefox windows]

Another showing a spotify window:
[image: another showing a spotify window]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of a blurred thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same issue on several of our workstations running Creators update, and pinpointed the issue to **patch KB4022725**.

As it is currently impossible to just ignore one single patch, we were forced to disable Windows Update for users who feel it is imperative to have proper taskbar windows previews.

EDIT: The hack to increase taskbar preview size addressed in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/548104/increase-windows-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-size) provides larger thumbnails indeed, but they are still scrambled. The problem actually appears to be with window preview images generated by the OS (as used for Alt-Tab task switching for example) rather than with taskbar thumbnails per se.

EDIT2: The patch also seems to break old applications, such as Adobe Illustrator CS, regardless of compatibility settings.